# gulp-rename makes copies, but does not replace

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-rename

Im trying to rename a batch of files.

```
gulp.task('rename', ['jade'], function() {
  gulp.src("public/build/*.html")
    .pipe(rename(function (path) {
      path.dirname += "/";
      path.basename += "";
      path.extname = ""
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("public/build"));
  gulp.src("public/build/story/*.html")
    .pipe(rename(function (path) {
      path.dirname += "/";
      path.basename += "";
      path.extname = ""
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/build/story'));
  gulp.src("public/build/work/*.html")
    .pipe(rename(function (path) {
      path.dirname += "/";
      path.basename += "";
      path.extname = ""
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/build/work'));
});
```

This method finds the files I want to change and does the job, but it makes a entirely new files, and does not replace the old file.  So im left with doubles of my batch, is there anything i should be adding to have this not happen?

Comment: I don't believe gulp-rename is supposed to replace your currently files, I am pretty sure it's supposed to just rename them and put them in a different directory. It's used when preparing an application for distribution. If you want to look into also removing files I would checkout out gulp-rimraf. https://github.com/robrich/gulp-rimraf

Comment: thanks so much, .. i had just come to that conclusion this morning rimraf worked perfectly

Comment: Sweet. Gonna post as an answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe gulp-rename is supposed to replace your currently files, I am pretty sure it's supposed to just rename them and put them in a different directory. It's used when preparing an application for distribution. If you want to look into also removing files I would checkout out gulp-rimraf. github.com/robrich/gulp-rimraf